# How to fix toggle sections issue in the toc of a bookdown?

Tags: r, bookdown

After cloning the [bookdown-demo](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo). I want to use the toggle function of sections.

For this, I modified the file `_output.yml` adding the collapse line:

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  config:
    toc:
      collapse: section
```

As shown in: [bookdown manual](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html)

And added some sections in `index.Rmd`

```
# Prerequisites

## second

### third
```

After building the book in Rstudio, with:

```
bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", "bookdown::gitbook")
```

It works with a little defect. When I click some chapter without sections, (and also sometimes the chapter with sections), there is a rapid movement of the menu as if it opens and immediately closes the sections of the (other) chapter with sections.

Does someone have a solution?

Possibly related issue: https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/556